# Change a value on a row with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe such as:

```
df.columns = ["qseqid", "sseqid", "pident", "length", "mismatch", "gapopen","qstart", "qend", "sstart", "send", "evalue", "bitscore"]
```

end the idea is to create a new column called `strand`

and if the value in start is higher than the end, then to add a + in the corresponding row and the same but `-` if start is lower than end.

here is my code:

```
for a, b in zip(df["qstart"],df["qend"]):
    if a > b:
        df['e'] = '+'
    elif a < b:
        df.['e'] = '-'
```

But I get in the column strand just `-` signes even if the value in `qstart` is higher than `qend`

Thank you for your help

df:

```
qseqid  sseqid  pident  length  mismatch    gapopen qstart  qend    sstart  send    evalue  bitscore
scaffold_1  test    25.5    337 166 9   2   20  27  310 1.0e-16 94.0
scaffold_1  tes2    27.0    278 163 9   500 20  222 487 1.e-16  94.0
scaffold_1  tes4    35.5    166 93  2   3   10  63  227 2.e-15  89.7
```

rest I should get:

```
qseqid  sseqid  pident  length  mismatch    gapopen qstart  qend    sstart  send    evalue  bitscore    strand
scaffold_1  test    25.5    337 166 9   2   20  27  310 1.0e-16 94.0    +
scaffold_1  tes2    27.0    278 163 9   500 20  222 487 1.e-16  94.0    -
scaffold_1  tes4    35.5    166 93  2   3   10  63  227 2.e-15  89.7    +
```

Other part:

0

I have a df such as:

```
qseqid  sseqid  pident  length  mismatch    gapopen qstart  qend    sstart  send    evalue  bitscore
scaffold_1  test    25.5    337 166 9   2   20  27  310 1.0e-16 94.0
scaffold_1  tes2    27.0    278 163 9   500 20  222 487 1.e-16  94.0
scaffold_1  tes4    35.5    166 93  2   3   10  63  227 2.e-15  89.7
```

and I would like to change the values in `df.qstart` and `ds.qend` if `df.qstart>df.qstart`

Here it would be:

```
qseqid  sseqid  pident  length  mismatch    gapopen qstart  qend    sstart  send    evalue  bitscore
    scaffold_1  test    25.5    337 166 9   2   20  27  310 1.0e-16 94.0
    scaffold_1  tes2    27.0    278 163 9   20 500  222 487 1.e-16  94.0
    scaffold_1  tes4    35.5    166 93  2   3   10  63  227 2.e-15  89.7
```

as you can se 500 was put in the place of 20 Thank for your help

Comment: None of the names and expected outputs appear to match up. What is `blast`, `'e'`, `'qstart'`, `'qend'`? And where is `'strand'`?

Comment: please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What if values are same?

Comment: It is not possible normally

Comment: Use @W-B’s solution for this, but for your knowledge, the issue is that your loop keeps setting the value for the *entire* column, not just a single cell.

Answer (score 1):

You can using `np.where`

```
df['e']=np.where(df["qstart"]>df["qend"],'+','-')
```

Comment: And do you know how can I change the value in `qstart` by the one in `qend` if `qstart` > `qend` as well?

Comment: @bewolf np.where(df["qstart"]>df["qend"],'do some',df["qstart"])

Comment: I edited my post to explain it better, because it does not work, I steal have the same tab with this code.

Comment: @bewolf look at sort values . also , if you have addtional question , the best way is to open a new question rather than edit your old question to get the answer.